# Why doesn't HttpContext.SignOutAsync invalidate the authentication cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1, and I am building a website which uses the pretty basic kind of authentication, with cookies. I am using the builtin functionality for this, i.e. `HTTPContext.SignInAsync` and `HTTPContext.SignOutAsync`. It works well in the browser, I sign in, sign out, the `ControllerBase.User` property works as expected.

But I am also going to use that authentication for a REST API, and I am encountering a strange behavior. I am not sure whether it is a bug, or a feature, or just a misunderstanding, but after I sign out, if I keep the cookie in the headers, the `User` property still remains set, and access is allowed, even with `[Authorize]`.

Is that supposed to happen? It does not seem logical. Signing out means closing the session, which means you have to sign in again to perform actions which require authentication.

But if this behavior is normal, what do I have to do to manually invalidate the authentication cookie on sign-out?

I can provide a minimal code to replicate this behavior on request.

Comment: You can set  cookie expiration . Look [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0#react-to-back-end-changes) to know more.

Comment: @QingGuo I am not sure how that CookieAuthenticationEvents thing helps, except if I do something overly intricate. Can you elaborate?

Comment: When ExpiresUtc is set, it overrides the value of the ExpireTimeSpan option of CookieAuthenticationOptions, if set. look here:[Absolute cookie expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0#absolute-cookie-expiration)

Comment: @QingGuo But the example it gives is a sign in. Are you saying if I give `new AuthenticationProperties {ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow}` to `SignOutAsync`, it will instantly invalidate the cookie?

Comment: "One approach to cookie validation is based on keeping track of when the user database changes. If the database hasn't been changed since the user's cookie was issued, there's no need to re-authenticate the user if their cookie is still valid. In the sample app, the database is implemented in IUserRepository and stores a LastChanged value. When a user is updated in the database, the LastChanged value is set to the current time." Have a look .

Comment: @QingGuo are you suggesting I keep a static list somewhere of users who've logged out, and reject them based on whether they are in that list or not?